# Is it possible to convert carbon soot/ black carbon in mg to CO2-equivalent? If so, how?

Tags: energy, condensed-matter, energy-conservation, units, physical-chemistry

Since global warming is expressed in terms of carbon emissions or CO2 equivalent, can the short lived carbon soot/ black carbon that is produced from incomplete combustion be expressed in terms of CO2 equivalent? I learnt Carbon soot is a major health risk. The purpose of doing this is to calculate how much of heating effect can be reduced by controlling the emissions of these carbon particles.

Comment: I believe that would depend on what you are burning, and to what extent the exothermic reaction progressed in the material. Is there material left that wasn't burned at all? Do you want to factor the potential C02 release from that too? You can definitely calculate it, but there are a lot of factors you would have to account for to get an accurate figure.

Comment: Thanks for sharing such factors. I wasnt much aware of it. Let's assume the material is burnt completely. If you can explain me with any generic example, say the output of a brick kiln, it'd be great.

Comment: [Black carbon-Radiative forcing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_carbon#Radiative_forcing)